# Laravel return after post is null with stored procedure

Tags: laravel, null

I have store **method** with return like this :

```
return redirect()->route('hasil.transaksi', ["data" => $data]);
```

with the **route** like this :

```
ROUTE::GET('hasil-transaksi', [KasirRajalController::class, 'hasilTransaksi'])->name('hasil.transaksi');
```

And method return like this :

```
    public function hasilTransaksi(Request $request)
{
    $data["info"] = DB::select("EXEC spx_kasirirj_GetData
    @sdata = 2,
    @where = '" . $request->no_transaksi . "'
    ");

    dd($data);
}
```

URL after store like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/hasil-transaksi?data%5B0%5D%5B%5D=0000260&data%5B0%5D%5Bno_transaksi%5D=KRJ22010001
```

I want to catch no_transaksi=**KRJ22010001**  to paste in the method return above. But i don't get it, the result is null.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxC3I.png)

Please, help?

Full dd($request) :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkIDM.png)

Comment: paste the dump of request object dd($request); and try passing the value like this url/path?no_transaksi=somevalue

Comment: Maybe decode the first and then access the values `(decodeURI('user%5Blogin%5D=username&user%5Bpassword%5D=123456'))`

Comment: dd($request) for no_transaksi is null to, but it given KRJ after submit. What goes wrong?

Comment: Can you please show full dd($request)

Comment: Your `DB::select(...)` is wide open to SQL injection. Definitely use a parameterised query instead

Comment: @SaiTarun please kinda check this post, i added full image there.

Comment: @Joundill but i need that stored procedure to process, idk .__.

Comment: Don't use unsanitised string concatenation to generate your queries. It's a huge security hole

Comment: Have a read of what causes it, and how to fix it [here](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things to review in your code:

- `return redirect()->route('hasil.transaksi', ["data" => $data]);`

This will do a GET redirect, so the `$data` object will be added as GET parameter and encoded (from object to string). That is why your URL only parameter is "data" (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/hasil-transaksi?data=`) and then the encoded data.

Your decoded URL data looks like this `data[0][]=0000260&data[0][no_transaksi]=KRJ22010001`.

This format seems a bit strange, but I don't have enough code to confirm. You could do this (assuming you don't need your `0000260` parameter [that should be keyed]):

`return redirect()->route('hasil.transaksi', ["no_transaksi" => $data[0]['no_transaksi']]);`

This should generate a correct URL `?no_transaksi=xx` and so `$request->no_transaksi` should work (that you should also sanitize).

- `@where = '" . $request->no_transaksi . "'`

As @Joundill mentioned, this part of your raw query is opened to SQL injection. If you don't use [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent), [Models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) or [Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests), you should at least sanitize and validate the `no_transaksi` request param value.